# Opera widgets not showing in drop down menu

Tags: opera

Just a quick curious question, I'm running Opera 11 and my widgets do not show in the drop down menu items, only; "Get Widgets", "Manage Widgets", "What are Opera Widgets?".  Shouldn't the widgets show in here?

Instead the only way to get to run widgets is through the sidepanel, I'm curious as if they weren't going to allow you to select a widget why not move the item into the Tool menu, alongside the extensions?  My question is, why this designed or do I have a problem?

[image]

Comment: {smiling} You do have problem as few people will know **why** it's that way... You might get some insights from Opera's forum. And you should request that feature in [Opera's wish-list](http://my.cn.opera.com/community/forums/forum.dml?id=24). I'll second you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They used to show in the menu which you speak of a few versions back then they became only accessible through the sidepanel. I figured it was a bug and it would be fixed but two maybe three opera versions have passed and it's still "broken" as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in agreement.  I guess we'll have to wait for the eventual bug fix.  Do you have an opera bug report?

Comment: Seems with Opera 12 widgets have been dropped, I guess that was the reason this remained unfixed for so long.  http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2012/04/24/end-unite-apps-and-widgets